# How to use pointer to an array of custom objects in ctypes

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I have a `ctypes` structure defined like this:

```
class CNode(Structure):
    pass


CNode._fields_ = [
    ("type", c_int32),
    ("children", POINTER(CNode)),
]
```

Here, `CNode` is used to represent a tree where the `children` field is supposed to point to a list of other `CNode` types. I have another function which generates a `CNode` tree from a tree which uses different Python class. I'm populating `children` like this:

```
def gen_c_tree(tree):
    cnode = gen_c_node(tree)

    if len(tree.children) > 0:
        tmp = [gen_c_node(child) for child in tree.children]
        cnode.children = POINTER(CNode * len(tree.children))(*tmp)

    return cnode
```

But, I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "path/file", line 32, in <module>
    genctree.gen_c_tree(parser.tree)
  File "path/file", line 29, in gen_c_tree
    cnode.children = POINTER(CNode * len(tree.children))(*tmp)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: incompatible types, LP_CNode_Array_1 instance instead of LP_CNode instance
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: @user7860670 Sorry for the confusion, there was some old code, updated the Question, there's only one class called `CNode`.

Comment: How does `CNode` know how many children to expect?

Comment: @MarkTolonen it doesn't. in the original object children is just a python list, a node can have 0 to n number of nodes in the children list. That's why I'm using `len(tree.children)`

Comment: Then you either need to dynamically generate the class with a pointer to fixed-sized array, or add a field that indicates the length and assign the pointer to the first element of the array.